# Tabbed application won't show Login view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application in Xcode 4.3 and I'm trying to insert a login screen before the tabbar is shown. The app works OK if `presentModalViewController` has `animated:YES`but if it is without animation the view is not showing.

```
@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    LogInViewController *logViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];

    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:logViewController animated:YES];
    //This wont work
    //[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:logViewController animated:NO];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

-(void)loginDone{

    NSLog(@"back to the app delegate");
   [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

1. Is this the right way to do it?
2. Why wont the code work with `animated:NO` ?
3. I also get this on output `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x689d350>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, move `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` before your view controller setup.

Additionally, you should be presenting the modal view controller within the `viewWillAppear:` method of the view controller that will be visible first, to make sure your apps view hierarchy has been fully initialized before presenting your login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
[self.window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
```

Do this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
```

This will put the `tabBarController` on the screen. But that's not exactly what you want... My advise is:

1) Start by putting the `logViewController` has the `rootViewController` as I showed you above.

2) Once you got what you want (login is successful) just tell the AppDelegate to switch the `rootViewController`. This can be done in with delegation or notifications.

Also, as Toastor indirectly pointed out, you should start the presentViewController from the `UIViewController` who actually initiates it (and not from the AppDelegate).